# Running Poisson Regression with Categorical variables (using Python)

Tags: python, statistics, regression, poisson

For an auctions website I run, I'm aiming to find which features have the highest influence on bids received. This way, I can focus my energies on improving features that matter the most.

I've been [advised](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/296842/infering-relative-importance-of-features-in-driving-a-dependent-variable) to run a Poisson Regression analysis for this purpose. This question is about getting the data ready for regression, and then running the actual regression. I'm using Python for this purpose.

**The data:** The dataset comprises auctions that lived for precisely 7 days. There is a mix of continuous and categorical features. Continuous ones are `asking_price`, `description_char_count` and `num_of_photos`.

Categorical variables are `city`, `item_category` and `item_condition`.

The dependent variable is `net_unique_bids`.

How do I handle the categorical variables?

**Dummy variables:** Correct me if I'm wrong - but I think I need to do the following:

```
# convert categorical columns
cities = pd.get_dummies(df['city'], drop_first=True)
categ = pd.get_dummies(df['item_category'], drop_first=True)
cond = pd.get_dummies(df['item_condition'], drop_first=True)

# add to main dataframe 'df'
df = pd.concat([df,cities,categ, cond], axis=1)

# remove original categorical columns
df.drop('city',axis=1, inplace=True)
df.drop('item_category',axis=1, inplace=True)
df.drop('item_condition',axis=1, inplace=True)
```

**Running Poisson Regression:** If this is correct so far, the next steps entail:

```
from statsmodels.genmod.generalized_estimating_equations import GEE
from statsmodels.genmod.cov_struct import (Exchangeable,
    Independence,Autoregressive)
from statsmodels.genmod.families import Poisson

f1 = "net_unique_bids ~ city1 + city2 + city3 + city4 + item_category1 + item_category2 + item_category3 + item_condition1 + item_condition2 + item_condition3 + asking_price + description_char_count + num_of_photos"
model1 = GEE.from_formula(formula=f1, data=df, cov_struct=Independence(), family=Poisson())
```

Do I have the right idea around how to handle categorical variables? Am I running Poission Regression correctly (and have I formulated `f1` correctly as well)?

If not, help me fill out the gaps.

---

*Note: I got my guidance on Poisson Regression in Python from [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/umich.box.com/shared/static/ir0bnkup9rywmqd54zvm.ipynb).*